# How do I trigger javascript events when a signature is cleared in Acrobat 11?

Tags: javascript, pdf, events, adobe, acrobat

In Adobe Acrobat Standard XI (11), is there a way to trigger a JavaScript event when a signature is *cleared*?

There is a built-in interface for performing certain actions when a signature is *added*, but not for when it is *removed*.

I want to lock down certain fields when the signature is added, and also auto-populate a date field next to the signature. My code for this is working fine. The problem is, when this signature is cleared, I want to *unlock* all those fields I previously locked down, and then *remove* the date.

When using the built-in "Lock these fields" feature of the signature actions, it successfully locks and unlocks the fields when the signature is added and removed, but it cannot be further customized to populate a date field as well.

If it really comes down to it, I can just ditch my custom date code, but I really want there to be a way to make this work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion by **Max Wyss**, I found a solution that works quite nicely. The calculated value field was the key. Though I didn't use the `signatureValidation()` method since this is not recommended by the documentation, it was unnecessary because I only needed to check for the presence of a signature.

This is all I needed. In the calculated custom script for my date field:

```
if (getField("mySig").value !== '') // signature is present
    getField("myDate").value = global.getCurDate(); // custom function for a mm/dd/yyyy date
else
    getField("myDate").value = '';
```

This may not be the final solution to *my* problem as this will calculate the date quite often, where I want the date to appear *once* when the field is signed and then to remain there indefinitely, but it *does* answer how to trigger an event when a signature is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have a specific event "clear signature". However, you can validate a signature field using the `signatureValidate()` Field Object method. For a code sample and further information see the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

You may have to find a suitable trigger for this action (autocalculate would be possible, but the documentation states that running this method is time-consuming, and that's something you do not want to have in the Calculation events.